# Vue CLI3 instant prototyping import CSS

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

How do I add or import CSS to instant prototyping with Vue CLI3?

I serve my prototype via `vue serve MyComponent.vue` but if I add `<style>` tags into the template it is ignored...

I would like to import Tailwind CSS.

```
<template>
  <div id="ds-configurator" class="test">
    Test
    dva
  </div>
</template>

<!-- this is ignored when served -->
<style>
html, body {
  height:100%;
  min-height:100%;
}

#ds-configurator, .test {
  background: #eee;
}
<style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out I can provide my own `index.html` where I can import Tailwind CSS or anything else.